# Avoid losing information when adding vector tiles to QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles

In Open Infrastructure Map I see things as below:

[image]

There are two types of power lines, one with 220kV (red) and another one with 60kV (brown).

But when I add this to QGIS it's all the same (green), how can I avoid that?

[image]

Comment: That's just the symbology for the layer. I am unsure if you can copy from a web-served layer to a local feature class layer but try that first, otherwise the information on the kV *should* be in the data as a field called *voltage*, you should be able to set a similar symbology read more : https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html

Comment: Symbolize by category  https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html